# People Picker Field

Tags: 2013, javascript

I would like to get the value of a people picker field in NewForm.aspx (if a user has entered a name), take that value, and set it into the list.

The problem is that I'm getting the error "Invalid data has been used to update the list item". So, I figured that the value I'm storing is incorrect(?). I've looked at other solutions online but they don't offer much help.

Is there a proper way to get the value of a people picker field using jQuery and then add it into a list?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people field each user has a number, you need to use this number while storing it.

If you inspect the html of the people picker textbox after entering a user you can see his/her number in the html in an attribute.

Use that to store similar to way in the below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35686401/how-to-save-multi-people-picker-values-using-angularjs

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a way I can get this number through code?

Comment: Yes!
1. When you add a user to the textbox his account name gets added to an attribute(key)
Eg: i:0#.f|membership|abc.com
2. With this you can get the user's ID using spservices library. An example is shown in the below link
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37669.sharepoint-get-user-profile-details-using-spservices-jquery-library.aspx